# How to pass the first item in an array

Tags: jquery, arrays

I have the following function

```js
function getItems(source, debpth, parent) {
  var children = source; //source gets all my array data
  console.log(children);
  var nestedlist = $('<div></div>');
  if (children && children.length > 0) //in here its passing all the items.what i want to do is only pass a specific array
  {
    getLinks(nestedlist, children, ++debpth, parent); //gets all my data and passes it to css styling
  }
  return nestedlist.children().length > 0 ? nestedlist : null;
}
```

How do I pass an array that has only the TypeCode of 'HOR'?

This is my output for the `source`

```
{
  __type: "TreeNode:#Entities",
  TypeCode: "HOR",
  TypeID: "1",
  TypeName: "Home",
  Name: "test",
  …
}
```

it has multiple arrays but I just want the above one.

Comment: `ArrayName["TypeCode"]` / `ObjectName.TypeCode`

Comment: Can you show the array? You have given the object { ... }

Comment: So you have the children array that contains object? if yes you can make use of filter to find all the object that have typecode as hor.

Comment: @DeepakJha yes,the children array contains the object

Comment: Look at my answer below, that may have a method you can use directly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a look at this example that I have created for you,

```
var myarr = [{a:'1'},{a:'2'},{a:'2'},{a:'3'}];
var finalArr = myarr.filter(function(k,v){
                               if(k.a==2){return true;}
                               else{return false;}});
console.log(finalArr);// this will print an array made up of a==2
```

so in the same manner you can change your source.

```
var newSource = source.filter(function(k,v){
                       if(k.TypeCode =='HOR'){
                          return true;
                        } else { return false;}
                });
```

now your newSource array will have only the objects which have TypeCode as "HOR".

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery's `grep` at the beginning of your function.

```
var children = $.grep(source, function(c) {
    return c.TypeCode == "HOR";
});
```

`children` will be an array whose elements are only the objects of `source` with `TypeCode` set as `HOR`.

The original array (`source`) will be unaffected.

Note that the above code assumes that **every** element of `source` is an object with a property named `TypeCode`.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using the following function which uses the $.map for conversion and further condition check

```
function getItems(source, debpth, parent) {
  var children = $.map(source, function(value, index) {
                      return [value];
                 });//source gets all my array data

  var nestedlist = $('<div></div>');
  if (children && children.length > 0) //in here its passing all the items.what i want to do is only pass a specific array
  {
    for(item in children)
    {

      if(children[item] == "HOR")
      {
         //console.log("send"+source);
         getLinks(nestedlist, source , ++debpth, parent); //gets all my data and passes it to css styling
      }

    }

  }
  return nestedlist.children().length > 0 ? nestedlist : null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure this is the right solution for you. As of my understanding, you may write a function which returns the array which has Typecode="HOR". you may send this source to the function after passing to the below function(improvements are needed)

```
function filterJsonArray(source) {
    $.each(source, function(key, val) {
       if(val.TypeCode === "HOR") {
           return value;
       }
    });
}
```